# return a list in a column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R, and I'm looking to calculate a list based on row values using data.tables. I've currently tried the following code as an example

```
library("data.table")
 dt <- data.table (data.frame(name = c("A","B","C")), num = c(10,20,30))
dt [,seq := list(replicate(5,num)),by = .I]
```

However, it doesn't generate the list but instead repeats the value in `num` column to the `seq` column. As shown below

```
name     num    seq
A         10     10
B         20     20
C         30     30
```

The expected output is

```
name     num    seq
A         10     list(10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
B         20     list(20, 20, 20, 20, 20)
C         30     list(30, 30, 30, 30, 30)
```

How do I go about with this?

Comment: What is your desired output? Not clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish. Can you show a sample expected outcome?

Comment: The desired output is mentioned in the question as expected output

Comment: You mean `dt [,seq2 := list(list(replicate(5,num))), by = 1:nrow(dt)]`? As far as I can tell, `by=.I` silently does nothing.

Comment: I would go with `dt[, res := transpose(replicate(5, num, simplify = FALSE))]` instead of doing by row OPs

Comment: Is that cause it optimises it better?

Comment: In R, everything you do by row- well, just don't do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Frank and @David, the answer is

```
dt [,seq2 := list(list(replicate(5,num))), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

primarily cause by = .I silently does nothing.

Alternatively, you can do the following, as it is better to not do row wise operations.

```
dt[, res := transpose(replicate(5, num, simplify = FALSE))]
```

In a different direction, If you are looking to use dplyr

```
dt %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(seq = list(rep(num, 5)))
```

Comment: Though it seems like `replicate` isn't vectorized so you won't have much difference between the two IMO

Comment: Even in the case of 100,000 rows?

Comment: Actually it is only not vectorized over `n` so this should be faster IMO. It is easy to benchmark btw

Comment: Another option: `dt[, .(lapply(num, \`[\`, rep(1,5))) ]`

Comment: I know David and Frank will hate it, but the dplyr reads well here: `dt %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(seq = list(rep(num, 5)))`

Comment: @alistaire I hate it.